# electron_node bundle.js using a lot of CPU in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylance

I wonder what is the `electron_node bundle.js` process doing exactly in VS Code, it's using a lot of CPU and makes my laptop very noisy even when just editing a single file.

It looks it's from the pylance, but I don't see it in the vscode on another laptop. I'm confused where it's exactly from. Any insight would be appreciated.

I'm using vscode 1.54.3

[image]

**Update:**

Looks it's a pylance issue, after I downgrade it from 2021.3.3 to 2021.2.4. it's not consuming much cpu anymore.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the same bug, but I just filed this, which might be related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18759